# Nginx Non-WWW Redirect to WWW Record Issue

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, amazon-route53, elastic-beanstalk

I am running Nginx via an AWS ElasticBeanstalk application and have Https enabled through a load-balancer and forced Https redirect for www., but it appears that there is either an issue with my Route53 records or Nginx server block as when I try to access the root domain (non-www), it brings up a godaddy.com parked page rather than redirecting to `https://www.` GoDaddy was the original DNS, but I migrated my records to Route53. My server block config looks correct, but would this error most likely be due to records or would it be something related to my server config?

**Elastic Beanstalk Nginx Modification:**

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/02_www_redirect.conf":
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: "000644"
    content: |
      server {
        listen 80;   #listen for all the HTTP requests
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
      }

container_commands:
    01_reload_nginx:
        command: "sudo service nginx reload"
```

**Route53 Record Sets:**

```
example.com. A ALIAS www.example.com. (Id's)
www.example.com. A ALIAS example-eb-application.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com. (Id's)
```

Comment: It's not your browser's cache that's fooling you?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I tried in two separate browsers with and without incognito

Comment: If you get a GoDaddy parking page, you are getting a wrong DNS result from the name query. So you should check your nameservers are actually set to the ones provided by Route 53.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I figured something had to be happening with the nameserver configuration. Are you saying that something on the GoDaddy side is incorrect causing the nameservers to be incorrectly set or something in Route53? Any help or documentation would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Please check older post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41669583/redirect-non-www-to-www-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk

Or make following change

```
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
  rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 redirect;
}
```